# monacaでiOSのみメーラーが起動できない

Tags: javascript, ios, android, monaca

HTMLのボタンを押した後、JavaScriptを使ってメーラーを起動しようと試みてます。
アンドロイドではサンプルを拝見して何とか起動できました。
しかしiOSではうまく動作できず悩んでいます。

機種はiPad 2、iOS 9、コードは

```
function Mailer(){
  var mail_address = 'test_Android@testes.tes';
  var mail_content = "Android_testTesttest";

  if (monaca.isAndroid === true) {
    window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
      action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
      url: 'mailto:' + mail_address + '?body=' + mail_content
      },
      function() {},
      function() {}
    );
  } else if ( monaca.isIOS === true ) {
    var mailto = 'test_iOS@testes.tes';
    mailto = mailto + 
      "?subject=題目&body=本文。%0D%0A改行も試みてます。";

    location.href= mailto;
  }
}
```

いろいろなところで紹介されてるサンプルでは`location.href`で問題無いようなのですが、私の環境ではうまく動作しません。

Comment: 最初に @kishikawa katsumi さま編集ありがとうございました。

Comment: @Le Pere d'OO さま指示通りです。私のミスですね。直ちに修正して試してみます。お世話になりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @@Le Pere d'OO さま　夜遅くまでありがとうございます。早速、教えていただいた所をチェックしてみます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

(iPad2と明記されているのでこちらは関係ないとは思いますが…)
Xcode 7のSimulatorには、メーラー(「メール」(Mail)アプリ)は搭載されていないので、当然他のアプリからメーラーを開くことはできません。確認は実機で行っていますでしょうか。

あなたがiOS版で`location.href`に設定している値には(Android版の`url:`にあるような)`mailto:`スキームが含まれていません。

```
    var mailto = 'mailto:test_iOS@testes.tes';
```

のように、`location.href`に設定される値の先頭に"mailto:"を追加してみてください。

Monacaは使ったことがないので、通常のUIWebViewでの確認ですが、"mailto:"が含まれていない文字列を`location.href`に設定しても、メーラーが開くことはありません。

Comment: 指示通り mailto: を追加して実行、テストしました。結果動作しませんでした。何か他方法を考えてみるべきでしょう。

Comment: MonacaではなくCordovaに関する記事ですが、config.xmlに`<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />`が必要かもしれない、と書かれた記事がありました。MonacaもベースにはCordovaを使用しているはずですので、ご参考までに。

Comment: Le Pere d'OO さんの回答通り、`var mailto = "mailto:mymail@example.com?subject=こんにちは&body=本文%0D%0A改行も試みてます。"; location.href = mailto;` の形式で、メーラーを立ち上げられました。ただし、Monacaデバッガー (5.0.x系)ではメーラーは立ち上がりませんでした。また、config.xmlに`<allow-navigation href="*" />`も必要です。

Comment: 次期 Monacaデバッガー (6.0.0系)では、メーラーを立ち上げられるように対応する予定です。よろしくお願いします。